# Network printers not showing in PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters

Tags: c#, service, system.drawing, .net-4.8, windows-server-2019

I have a service running on a windows server 2019 VM that during setup will get a list of printers available using the below

```
 List<string> printers = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Cast<string>()
                                        .Select(printname => (string)printname)
                                        .ToList();
```

When run by the service this will get a list built in printers such as "Microsoft Print To PDF" etc.

But for some reason does not show network printers.

I have tried running the above code snippet in its own .exe and it is able to get the list of network printers.

Comment: What account is the service running under? Is the server in a domain? If so, is the user that you're running the service under in the same domain as the network printers?

Comment: Thanks @user246821, you pointed me in the right direction, the service was using the SYSTEM account. I changed that and now I can see the network printers.